# HP OfficeJet 4650 "scan to computer"

Tags: drivers, hp, scanner, protocol

I am new to Ubuntu. Version 18.04. I have a low-cost consumer AIO printer HP OfficeJet 4650 series. The scanner provides a function to *scan to computer*. You put the paper in the scanner and touch the scan button on the small display. All Windows computers are listed. You can choose a computer and run the scan. The document will be saved on the computer. This is shown on this video at time 01:47 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70GlNM9ytbc

My question is, is there a way that this also works with Ubuntu? Is there perhaps a special software? Or does anyone know what is behind it (which protocol for example)?

I installed the hp driver. Print and scan is working from the computer. But the scanner doesn't discover the Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can scan to a network folder on your PC...

## Create a File Share on Ubuntu

1. Make sure all your packages are up-to-date.

   1. In a terminal, execute the following.

      ```
      sudo apt upgrade
      ```
   2. Restart your computer.
2. Open files (a.k.a. Nautilus).
3. Right click on your "Public" folder in your home directory.
4. The "Public Properties" dialog will appear.
5. Click on the "Local Network Share" tab.

   [image: Public Properties dialog]
6. Select the "Share this folder" checkbox.
7. Click the <kbd>Install service</kbd> button when prompted, to install the sharing service.

   [image: Install Service dialog]
8. Click the <kbd>Install</kbd> button to confirm.

   [image: Install Confirmation dialog]

   [image: Applying Changes dialog]
9. Select the "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder" checkbox.
10. Select the "Guest access (for people without a user account)" checkbox.

    [image: Public Properties dialog]
11. On the dialog that appears, click the <kbd>Add permissions automatically</kbd> button.

    [image: Add Permissions Automatically dialog]

## Access Your Printer Configuration

1. Open a web browser and go to the IP Address of your printer.
2. You will be presented with the message "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead".
3. Click the <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> button.
4. Click the <kbd>Accept the Risk and Continue</kbd> button.

   [image: Potential Security Risk warning]
5. The HP Embedded Web Server page will appear.

   [image: HP Embedded Web Server page]

## Configure Your Printer

1. Click to the "Scan to Network Folder" tile.
2. Click the "+" icon to add a new Network Folder to your printer.

   [image: Scan to Notwork Folder page]
3. Complete the "Step 1: Network Folder" page.

   1. Enter a display name for your new Network Folder.
   2. For Network Path, type `\\<YOUR COMPUTER NAME>\Public`.

      Replace `<YOUR COMPUTER NAME>` with the host name of your computer. In some cases you may need to add `.local` at the end. You can also use your computer's IP address, if you are using static IP addresses.
   3. Click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button.

   [image: Step 1 page]
4. Complete the "Step 2: Log-in Authentication" page.

   1. Click the "Use Credentials of the user currently signed in" checkbox.
   2. Click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button.

   [image: Step 2 page]
5. Complete the "Step 3: Setup Configuration" page.

   1. Enter general information for scanned documents.
   2. It's a good idea to set the "Default File Name" and the "File Name Suffix".
   3. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button. (If you had specified user credentials, click the <kbd>Save and Test</kbd> button).

   [image: Step 3 page]

## Scanning on Your Printer

To scan documents to your computer, do the following on you printer:

1. Click the <kbd>Scan</kbd> button.
2. Click the "Network Folder" icon.
3. Click the <kbd>Start Scan</kbd> button.
4. The scanned document will be saved to your computer in your Public folder.

Comment: Good to know. My HP network printer/scanner is old and does not have this feature available on its web page.

Comment: You can also set this up using the control panel on some HP printers. The owner's manual for the HP 4650 indicates that it does have the "Embedded Web Server (EWS)", but HP doesn't clarify which specific features are available in the EWS, for different printer models. So I guess it depends on which printer you have. @user68186, what does it say in the "Scan to PC" column for your printer in the [HP Supported Printer Models](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) list?

Comment: Thanks! The model is Photosmat C6250. It says "yes" in the "Scan to PC" column in that page. Here is a [picture of the printer's web page](https://imgur.com/a/Ro6jORD). As you see it is very different from yours.

Comment: @user68186, you may be out of luck. [Note 3](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index#note3) specifies: "Scan supported means that PC initiated scan using a SANE compatible software". (Basically, you can only scan from your Linux PC). However, if you have the HP Windows software, you may be able run it in a virtual machine, such as VirtualBox. Then create a vBox shared folder, configure the HP software to save to the VBox shared folder, and scans will be saved to into your Ubuntu file system. ...Not sure if this is worth the effort, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this https://github.com/manuc66/node-hp-scan-to it supports some devices and yours might be working you can use it with npx or with docker

Usage with npx:
`npx node-hp-scan-to -ip 192.168.1.88 -d /tmp/scan-to-pc`